# how to approach a reward system

Tags: algorithm, reward-system

I have a website where I've done a "mission generator" to encourage engagement. I've hard coded 3 sets of missions (Easy, Med, Hard).

**Easy missions have 6-8 cases that could randomly happen**

- Update N times your hero (N is random number)
- Update specific skill
- Rest your hero for a day
- etc..

**Med and Hard require 1 task which is harder to achieve and adds two from the Easy tasks.**

My generator works great but I would like to know how to design the reward system so that it is hard to game by the users.

**The problems that I have are sort of:**

- The user might decide to quickly achieve the tasks and then delete them as soon as they get the "achieved badge"

*For example*

- Update 3 times your hero
- Add a new skill
- Send a message to another hero

What I see as a problem is that the person might decide to update 3 times, choose a new skill and send a message, then erase the 3 updates (there is such a feature) remove the skill and delete the message that he has send.

**So far I've come up with the following ideas but I'm looking for an opinion from someone who has done something like that.**

**- First approach:** 
Hard-code a table in the database with columns for each possible combination say
row1 - Updates | row2 - New skills etc... 
Downside: I'm afraid that the row could end up very long and it would be hard to manage and add new types of challenges. The whole concept become very rigid.

**- Second Approach:** 
For every task assign a unique id and once a skill or update or whatever is added append that to the task number.
Downside: every member gets 3 daily missions (which could be extended in time) if the generator requires on average 3 updates per mission that makes it to roughly 10 updates per user per day, adding to that the actual records for the updates with the data it adds up pretty quickly for a couple of thousand users. I would say 90% of this data will be useless and will just generate bills.

**- Third approach:**
Add a column to the table with the updates, skills (and all the other tables which are used in the missions). Then, when the user adds a new skill (for instance) the challenge ID will be added to the column in the skills table, then if the skill is removed the mission will fall back to "unachieved" (same goes for the updates and the other skills)
Downside: This might turn out very messy when the challenge is "put hero to rest for 1 day" because if the generator asks that twice between two days, the user will lose the first achievement of that sort because the challenge ID will be overwritten.

A big question is - what happens when the user decides to cut corners and delete some of their skills. I presume their missions will start piling up? (kind of like a punishment)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about game mechanics

Comment: @MikeW I disagree. The question is as much game mechanics as database design and algorithms. There are other questions at stackoverflow which discuss different reward systems hence I decided to post my question here.

Comment: @Ando I suggest asking your question in the theoretical forum: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com .. where you'll get better answer in algorithms

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer It's not exactly a research-level question, thus not appropriate for [cstheory.se].

Comment: @Dukeling You're right, it's not a research-level question, but it's not a technical one either .. maybe he can ask in the game dev forum

Comment: You'd probably need to get into a bit more detail as to how all this works (I'm not really getting it). To me it sounds like a database design question, which **might** be better suited on [dba.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making some things more dynamic.

For example: You could put the skills in a static checkbox list on the side, and select or deselect them. Then add a button to delete the selected skill, and skills are added to the static checkbox list by selecting a skill on the page itself, outside of the checkbox list.
The skill is then added to the checkbox list as an element.

When you need to rest your character for a day, it's pretty much impossible to do that twice in one day. Make it so that the rest for a day event can only happen once in a day.
This way there is no need to worry about overwriting, and the player doesn't get confused as to why his hero needs to rest twice. Perhaps make the resting bound to a stamina bar that decreases with certain events. When you add a skill perhaps the training can cost stamina. When the stamina runs out his hero needs to rest.

About removing updates and skills:
It is not a very good idea to make things removable right after being added.
Make it so that the skills and updates can only be removed after a certain time.
Long enough to confirm the achievement and store the achievement.
Then they are able to remove their skill and updates and the achievement which was already saved won't disappear.

Sending a message to the other hero:
I have a question about that.
Why would you be able to remove the message.
Is the message sent to another player?
If so, it would make no sense to be able to remove it.
Also, sending a message obviously happens server side since it goes to another player so you can set it to done server side.